# Error Android Object Detection App with model from tflite Model-maker

Tags: android, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am creating a custom Android App for object detection. Therefore, I use the Tensorflow Object Detection Android App from here: examples/lite/examples/object_detection/android at master · tensorflow/examples · GitHub
I am training my models with TFlite model maker with the following code:

```
!pip install -q tflite-model-maker
!pip install -q pycocotools

#----------------Python code--------------------------
import numpy as np
import os

from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.version.startswith(‘2’)

tf.get_logger().setLevel(‘ERROR’)
from absl import logging
logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)

spec = model_spec.get(‘efficientdet_lite0’)

test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(’./test’, ‘./test’, label_map={1: “Ball”, 2: “Spieler Rot”, 3: “Spieler Gelb”})
train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(’./train’, ‘./train’, label_map={1: “Ball”, 2: “Spieler Rot”, 3: “Spieler Gelb”})
validation_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(’./valid’, ‘./valid’, label_map={1: “Ball”, 2: “Spieler Rot”, 3: “Spieler Gelb”})
model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=16, train_whole_model=True, validation_data=validation_data, epochs=1)
model.evaluate(test_data)
model.export(export_dir=’.’)
```

This worked without any errors for many weeks. Now I get the following error in Android Studio:

```
Output tensor at index 0 is expected to have 3 dimensions, found 2.
```

My dataset is exactly the same and I train on Google Colab. I am sure that I didn’t change anything on the Android App.

Answer (score 0):

The above model maker for object detection tasks has an issue with TensorFlow 2.6 version currently, for the time-being. Please consider using TensorFlow 2.5 version for creating a model for the object detection tasks.

Comment: Thank you very much. We got help at the tensorflow forum: We recognized that the output neurons were in a different row at the new Version 2.6.

Comment: hi @danih1207 can you share to me the full details  how did you fix it ?

Comment: Hi :-) I just downgraded the Tensorflow Version.

Comment: pip install PyYaml==5.1
pip install tensorflow==2.5.0

Comment: I got very good help at the tensorflow forum. See: https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/object-detection-android-app-creates-error-with-model-from-tflite-model-maker-it-had-worked-for-many-weeks-a-until-a-few-weeks-ago/4015

Comment: now is sep 2022 - and I get the same error ... should I go back to 2.5 too ?